# How to properly start tor service

Tags: configuration, security, ubuntu, torsocks, startup

For months I've been using:

```
$ sudo systemctl start tor.service
```

but I just realized we can start tor by simply typing "tor" into a terminal. What's the proper/safest way to start and stop tor.service?

Answer (score 15):

Normally the Tor service should be started/stopped with either:

```
sudo systemctl start/stop tor.service
```

Or:

```
sudo service tor start/stop
```

Personally I've always used the `service` command because it is simpler. I'm guessing things get a little more complicated when you run multiple Tor instances, but I have no experience with that.

Running Tor in a terminal runs Tor as your user, and binds it to that terminal window. Running as a service allows Tor to run in the background with the proper permissions.

Comment: "Failed to start tor.service: Unit tor.service is masked"
This error when running any of the commands above..

Comment: I'm trying to start tor on my macbook pro but it wont start because "sudo: start: command not found" it says command not found for a lot of things and when i just type tor and press enter it seems like it starts but them my terminal wont do anything